# LoadSkin loop error

Tags: zend-framework, loops, skin

This is my LoadSkin view helper. I use this class to call the CSS files within an XML. See below:

```
public function loadSkin($skin)
{
    $skinData = new Zend_Config_Xml('./skins/' . $skin . '/skin.xml');
    $stylesheets = $skinData->stylesheets->stylesheet->toArray();

    if(is_array($stylesheets))
    {
        foreach($stylesheets as $stylesheet)
        {
            echo $this->view->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/skins/' . $skin . 
                    '/css/' . $stylesheet);
        }       
    }
}
```

But i have one problem, i have 3 CSS files:

- default.css
- text.css
- form.css

But the loop is wrong. First he takes the default.css. After he takes default.css and text.css. And finally he takes default.css, text.css and form.css. But i need only one loop working correctly.

Look below what's happen:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0iBA.png

Someone can help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are echoing inside foreach loop . HeadLink view helper is container in each iteration of loop you had appended/added css int it , as a result in each echo you are echoing the whole container which contains all the previous added css  hence do this instead

```
 if(is_array($stylesheets))
    {
        foreach($stylesheets as $stylesheet)
        {
             $this->view->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/skins/' . $skin . 
                    '/css/' . $stylesheet);
        }       
    }
```

Then in your layout.phtml inside  do

```
<head>
<?echo $this->headLink() ?>
</head>
```